# How to refresh Fragment datas when coming from previous screen android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to refresh fragment's data when it comes from previous screen.

Below is the code how it looks.

```
public class SettingsHomepageActivity extends FragmentActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    showFragment(new TopLevelSettings(), R.id.main_content);
    }
    
    private void showFragment(Fragment fragment, int id) {
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        final Fragment showFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(id);

        if (showFragment == null) {
            fragmentTransaction.add(id, fragment);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.show(showFragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}


TopSettings extends Fragment {

@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        use(SupportPreferenceController.class).setActivity(getActivity());
    }
}
```

In the above code, you can see showFragment is displaying only in onCreate().
Now when datas been updated in SupportPreferenceController and when user presses home button, it goes to onStart(), hence TopSettings will not be called
and hence Fragment will not get refreshed when datas get updated.

I used this below code in SettingsHomePageActivity,

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    this.recreate();
    super.onRestart();
}
```

But the above code always keep refreshing Fragments whenever we go to any page.

How to overcome this? I need to refresh fragment's datas but not the entire Fragment everytime.

Comment: in `onResume` have you tried calling the update data function ?

Comment: No. I used in onRestart..

Comment: Are you actually leaving the activity so that `onRestart()` can get called? Is it even being called, and have you verified that with some logs perhaps?

Comment: have a flag `isToRefreshData` and set its value to `true` when navigating to another fragment now in `onResume { if(isToRefreshData) UPDATE_DATA() }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh data in `onResume()` function. as we know when we come back to previous screen in that case `onResume()` is getting called so if you want to refresh or update the data, you should implement code in `onResume()` function.
One more suggestion is that try to maintain flag like `needToRefreshData=true` and check it in `onResume()`, otherwise it'll be refreshed unnecessary every time.